# Arranging data in rows in R

Tags: r

I have the OMIM gene list (about 15,000 genes) with corresponding diseases that looks like this:

```
SLC6A8,CRTR,CCDS1   Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352 (3)
BCAP31,BAP31,DXS1357E,DDCH  Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination
ABCD1,ALD,AMN   Adrenoleukodystrophy, 300100 (3), X-linked recessive
PLXNB3,PLXN6    NA
```

For some diseases, we have more than one gene name associated with a disease. I would like to organize this so I have only one genename per row and the associated disease:

```
SLC6A8 Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352 (3)
CRTR Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352 (3)
CCDS1 Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352 (3)
```

Could this be done in R?

Comment: *"Could this be done in R?"* -- most likely, but what have you tried so far? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have been using R for several things, but in this case I don't know where exactly I need to look. I would just like a hint, not necessarily the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what sort of data structure you have. Here's a quick solution that is hopefully helpful to what you're looking for:

```
splitFn <- function(x) expand.grid(df[x,"a"] %>% as.character %>% strsplit(., ",") %>% unlist, df[x, "b"])
ldply(1:nrow(df), splitFn)

       Var1                                                Var2
1    SLC6A8  Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352(3)
2      CRTR  Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352(3)
3     CCDS1  Cerebral creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352(3)
4    BCAP31    Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination
5     BAP31    Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination
6  DXS1357E    Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination
7      DDCH    Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination
8     ABCD1 Adrenoleukodystrophy, 300100(3), X-linked recessive
9       ALD Adrenoleukodystrophy, 300100(3), X-linked recessive
10      AMN Adrenoleukodystrophy, 300100(3), X-linked recessive
11   PLXNB3                                                <NA>
12    PLXN6                                                <NA>
```

The data.frame I'd used

````
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("ABCD1,ALD,AMN", 
"BCAP31,BAP31,DXS1357E,DDCH", "PLXNB3,PLXN6", "SLC6A8,CRTR,CCDS1"
), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, NA), .Label = c(" Cerebral 
creatine deficiency syndrome 1, 300352(3)", 
"Adrenoleukodystrophy, 300100(3), X-linked recessive", "Deafness, dystonia, and cerebral hypomyelination"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")```
````